# "newing" a function in JavaScript - what does it mean?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var f = function() { return 10; }
typeof f;                         // returns "function"
f();                              // returns 10

var g = f;
g();                              // returns 10, obviously

var h = new f;
h;                                // console evaluates to f - ????
h();                              // Type error - called_non_callable
typeof h;                         // returns "object"
```

So, what is h here?  The Chrome console seems to evaluate it as f, but it isn't callable.  What does it mean to "new" a function like this?  How is h now related to f?

As an aside, these two lines appear to be equivalent:

```
var h = new f;
var h = new f();
```

What's up with that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of your confusion is the way that Chrome represents objects on its console.

The expression `new f()` in your example is represented as '`f`' on the Chrome's console output, but just as a mere "convenience" of this particular console, for example, logging the following object:

```
({constructor: function Foo(){}});
```

Will show it represented as "`Foo`". Basically the console tries to find a *representation* of which constructor your object is *instance of*.

So, the console shows you `f`, but you are not logging the function, the `new` operator produces an object that inherits from `f.prototype`.

You are returning `10` from the function, but since you call it with `new`, and the return type is a *primitive*, the value is discarded, the newly created object that inherits form `f.prototype` is returned.

For example:

```
var F = function () { return 10; };
F.prototype.inherited = 'foo';

var h = new F(); // the 10 returned is ignored
h instanceof F; // true
h.inherited;    // "foo"
```

On the other hand, if you return an object from a constructor, the object instance that the `new` operator creates behind the scened (and inherits from the constructor's prototype) will be lost, for example:

```
var F = function () { return  {}; };
F.prototype.inherited = 'foo';

var h = new F(); // the empty object is returned
h instanceof F; // false
h.inherited;    // undefined
```

Yes, `new f;` and `new f();` are completely equivalent, although people recommend using the parentheses to add clarity to your code.

Comment: one of the best explanations on SO! Thank you for keeping it simple.

Answer (score 4):

this is how object-orientation in JavaScript works. if you call `new` on a function, this function would be treated as if it's a constructor of a class (the keywords `class` to define a class like other languages do doesn't exist in js).

so calling `var h = new f();` makes `h` an object of class `f`, and an object itself isn't callable (that's why you get `called_non_callable`).

if you want to give your "class" some methots, you should do it like this:

```
function cat(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.talk = function() {
        alert( this.name + " says meeow!" )
    }
} 

cat1 = new cat("felix")
cat1.talk() //alerts "felix says meeow!"

cat2 = new cat("ginger")
cat2.talk() //alerts "ginger says meeow!"
```

that's an example from [page 2](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml) of [this tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml). for more information, read that or [ask Google for object-orientation in JavaScript](http://www.google.de/search?q=object%20orientation%20javascript).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this, especially the section on "Function context".

In a nutshell, when you `new` function, you're creating a new object:
`var h = new f;`

This says: "Create a new object referenced by the variable named `h` of type `f`". The function is then treated as a constructor rather than what you're expecting.

Once the object has been created, it's no longer callable (which is why you're experiencing an error on the line `h()`.

In most language (Javascript not excluded), the `()` of a constructor are optional (unless there are required parameters (in some languages)).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the new keyword calls f as the constructor of a new object. The first reply to this question, on StackOverflow, sums it up quite nicely:

[What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, functions aren't just functions, and they're not just objects; they're also used to defined constructors for types.

Generally speaking, when you have a function `f`, that function defines a type, whether that was intended or not. So the line

```
var h = new f();
```

defines an object `h` whose type is `f`.

I've never seen the line

```
var h = new f;
```

but I'm assuming it does the same as the other line.